# How fully replace master and all its commits with another branch?

Tags: git

I've been trying to replace a repo's `master` branch with another branch but every way I try, it retains commits that aren't in the other branch. For example, the other branch has 121 commits but after the commands (both sets are below) master shows 216 commits!

**Attempt #1**

```
#Replacing master with otherBranch branch
git checkout otherBranch
git merge -s ours master
git checkout master
git merge otherBranch 
git push
```

**Attempt #2**

```
git checkout otherBranch
git push git@github.com:remoteRepo :master

#Also tried
git checkout otherBranch
git push git@github.com:remoteRepo +otherBranch:master
```

Both of these ended with the same result.

So how do I fully replace master with the other branch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

first make a backup of your master branch:

```
git branch master_backup master
```

then do the following to erase your current master and make otherBranch your new master:

```
git checkout master # switch to master branch
git reset --hard otherBranch # dangerous command: make master point to where otherBranch is. You will loose work that was on master branch and not on otherBranch
git push -f origin master # push this new master branch to origin; thereby crushing (-f) whatever was on master branch on origin
```